# How can I delete all pods via delete job

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-jobs

I created a job,and rerun it several times。
When I delete this job. Only the latest pod be deleted.

How Can I delete these pods all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**For Cronjob**

You can use the **successfulJobsHistoryLimit** to manage the pod count, if you will set it to **0**, POD will get removed as soon as it complete it's execution successfully.

```
successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
```

Read more at : https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#jobs-history-limits

GCP ref : https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/cronjobs#history-limit

**For Job**

If you are using job not cronjob you can use `ttlSecondsAfterFinished` - delete the job pod after set second automatically, you can set it accordingly keeping some buffer.

```
ttlSecondsAfterFinished: 100
```

will solve your issue.

Example : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#clean-up-finished-jobs-automatically

**Extra** :

You can delete those pods using simple command but that is one-time solution using the label in PODs or used in job

```
kubectl delete pods -l <labels> -n <namespace>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a label or you maybe have already one to match the targeted group of pods , so you can delete them all based on this label as follow:

```
  kubectl delete pods -l app=my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a number of pods from the same image, and you want to clean them up, and then have only one pod running? If so, you need to delete the deploy:

```
kubectl -n <namespace> get deploy
kubectl -n <namespace> delete deploy <deployname>
```

Or you can scale to 0 replicas:

```
kubectl scale deploy <deploy-name> --replicas=0
```

which will kill all these pods, and then apply the manifest anew, so it creates 1 pod (assuming you are not scaling to more than 1 active pod)

```
kubectl -n <namespace> apply -f <manifest-for-that-deploy.yaml>
```